# How to forward port on a dedicated windows server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

In MSDN to make SQL Server accessible from Internet
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175483.aspx

They say to forward port from sql server remote port to usual sql server port 1443.

I have at a hosting company 2 dedicated windows server 2008 which have Intel 82574L Gigabit Network Adapters. How can I do this on the computer that has SQL Server installed ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
C:\>netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=12345 listenaddress=192.168.A.B connectport=54321 connectaddress=192.168.X.Y
```

Where 12345 is your external port that you want to connect to, 54321 will be the destination port (your 1443). Address 192.168.A.B is the address where you access 12345 port and 192.168.X.Y is the address where you have port 54321 located. Both addresses can be the same in case you want to redirect the port on the same machine.

Comment: I forgot to mention that with command "netsh interface portproxy show all" you will get full list of forwarder ports on the machine

Answer (score 1):

First you need to allow incoming traffic to the port 1443 in the windows Firewall of the server that have installed SQL Server on it, then you need to access the hosting company control panel and view if there's a panel to configure port Forwarding, and then forward the port 1443 to the ip address of the server that have installed SQL Server ...

Comment: The external port is 2301 that's the one I put already in Firewall. What I need is to forward this one to 1443. I don't have any control panel at hosting service, it's a dedicated server with Remote Desktop Access and Full admin rights.

Comment: And my question is not about WHAT to forward but HOW to forward (command line I would type)